# Where is the key to the Chest of the Source King?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I just defeated Braccus Rex, but I can't find the key to the magically locked chest in his room. I've read that I can use an unlock scroll to open it, but I'd rather find the key. Where can I get it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the third act/map/whatever of the game, completing the quest "A Forge of Souls" in one manner (dunno if doing it the other way will work) will give you the key.

> I don't recall exactly when I got the key, but it was in the process of killing Cassandra (either she drops it or you get it from the "Temple of the Dead")

Though at that point the loot from the chest is useless.

Comment: This is the correct answer. His sister has the key in her grave.

Answer (score 3):

The purple padlock symbol indicates a magical lock, rather than a mechanical lock. Magical locks cannot be unlocked by mechanical means, such as keys or lockpicks. The only way to unlock them is with magic, specifically the [**Unlock Magic**](http://divinity.gamepedia.com/Unlock_Magic) spell or scroll (Witchcraft).

With a bit of luck you can craft one of these scrolls from a blank Witchcraft scroll, or learn the matching spell if you can find a spellbook. Or try to find/buy one.

Comment: the easiest unlock scroll to get in cyseal is sitting in Arhu's study

Comment: Googling this before asking didn't give me an answer I understood about where the key existed, but it did seem to repeatedly indicate that there is one that shows up a bit later in the game. Are you sure there isn't one?

Answer (score 0):

You loot "Key of the Source King" in the Temple of the Dead:

[image: "An old key. Now to find what it can unlock…"]

> from Cassandra's body which is buried behind a secret "door" you can walk through.

Comment: If you read the spoiler tag on the accept answer, this doesn't add anything new